# Why Sun's coronal belt is more stable at Sun's equator?

Tags: magnetic-fields, astrophysics, sun

As the Sun's coronal belt is made up of protons and electrons constantly scattered by photosphere's sunlight and as these particles are forced to do loops due to Sun's magnetic field is it possible that they are more stable at the equator because the magnetic field orientation doesn't permit them to go further into space when scattered by photosphere sunlight?

Comment: The Sun's magnetic field is so complicated, there is little preference for stability anywhere.  There is a preference for open magnetic fields (i.e., those not immediately connecting back to the sun) near the poles, which results in higher speed flow and lower density (i.e., less light is seen in coronagraphs).  Is this to what you are referring?